# assigning http/listener port to oracle says invalid

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, centos, centos7

I installed oracle 11g XE on Centos 7 and then uninstalled it - then on trying to configure oracle-xe after reinstalling it I found this problem while assigning ports:

```
Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:y
Invalid http port: y
```

While installing it for the first time I had no problem setting `8080` as the `hhtp` port and `1521` as the `listener` port.

I tried killing both of these ports by `fuser 8080/tcp` but it didn't help.

In the end I had to assign another port `8181` to it - How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: don't hit Y, just hit enter and it'll take the default (8080)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith okay but now that I have assigned new ports I really like to know if the assigned port gets freed after yum installing? Or do I need to do something else?